# how to put a watermark text in top left corner in browsers

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

im looking about how to put a watermark text in my webpages in left top corner over all the content
that is, independently of the content of the pages, have always a watermark text

have readed about brianium/watermarkjs but seems this for iamges watermarking.

Comment: use fixed position content

Comment: can you give some more information please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made this code on codepen so you can see it.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZyjRV)

```
<div id="watermark">
    <p>Watermark</p>
</div>

#watermark {
    color: #d0d0d0;
    font-size: 20pt;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     z-index: -1;
     left:-45px;
     top: -500px;
}
```